# Mat-icon does not center in its div

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I am very new to css and I cannot align the mat-icon (the thought bubble) to the div class=img (the green square on the left) - see the attached image. At this moment the icon is a little bit near the top

For adding the svg icon I used Material Angular - MatIconRegistry class (don't know if it matters)

My result:
[image]

Here is my html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="img"><mat-icon svgIcon="info"></mat-icon></div>
  Some text here!
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
$conainer-min-width: 256px !default;
$conainer-max-width: 512px !default;
$conainer-height: 50px !default;

div.container {
  max-width: $container-max-width;
  min-width: $container-min-width;
  height: $container-height;
  margin: auto;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  line-height: $container-height;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #9e9e9e;
  padding-right: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 30px;
}


div.img {
  width: $container-height;
  height: $container-height;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-color: #9e9e9e;
  line-height: $container-height;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #3f9c35;
}
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

**Using FLEX with a container element for each icon/text:** **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbpfnh-xwmv5h?file=app%2Ficon-overview-example.html)**

CSS:

```css
.icon-text {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="icon-text">
   <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
   <span>Some text here 1</span>
</div>
```

---

You can add `vertical align` to the `mat-icon` element or `.mat-icon` class:

**To override all material icons with global CSS:**  **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbpfnh-apg4gt?file=app%2Ficon-overview-example.html)**

```css
.mat-icon {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

ATENTION: If your text have capital letters, add negative margin  to prevent visual issues on some browsers ([Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbpfnh-bqphuc?file=app%2Ficon-overview-example.html)). 
Also you can simply use `vertical-align: sub` or `vertical-align: bottom` if fits better with your requirements. Check following [alignment  MDN demo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

---

**To style a particular material icon with utility class:** **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbpfnh-kqh9kn?file=app%2Ficon-overview-example.html)**

*In some global css file:*

```css
.v-align-middle { 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

*HTML:*

```
<div>
   <mat-icon class="v-align-middle">home</mat-icon>
   <span class="v-align-middle">Some text here 1</span>
</div>
```

** *some css frameworks already have classes like this, eg: bootstrap 4* **

---

**To style a particular material icon:** **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbpfnh-hx4tth?file=app%2Ficon-overview-example.html)**

CSS:

```css
.custom-class mat-icon {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/** or using the class .mat-icon */
.custom-class .mat-icon {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="custom-class">
   <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
   <span>Some text here 1</span>
</div>
```

Comment: As suggested [here](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/121), set `display: flex;` in parent div may give you better control.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. After some tests I personaly like 'vertical-align: sub' better.
The icons are a bit too low with 'vertical-align: middle'.

Comment: How come this doesn't work if there is a `height` style on the parent container?

Comment: @trebor if you are using the global override, use `line-height` in the parent container to get a vertical center text/icon. DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbpfnh-oe4xm5?file=app%2Ficon-overview-example.css

Comment: good works. However, in my case, only the 2nd solution with flex work.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the flex Layout to align the icon

```html
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center">
  <mat-icon fxFlexAlign="center">supervisor_account</mat-icon>
</div>
```

Read more about flexLayout in the documentation, fxLayout row is the same as:

```css
div {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:center; /* For fxLayoutAlign="center" */
}
```

Then you further align the flex item to center i.e `fxFlexAlign="center"`

```css
mat-icon {
  display:flex;             
  align-self:center; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What works for me is to use *flex-container* (justify-content / align-items to center) along with these properties `font-size`, `width`and `height` - depending on your font size, which drives the other two properties:

```css
::ng-deep .mat-icon {
  font-size: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is typo on these variable names:

> $conainer-min-width: 256px !default; 
>   $conainer-max-width: 512px !default; 
>   $conainer-height: 50px !default;

which doesn't match the variables used here:

> div.container { 
>     max-width: $container-max-width; 
>     min-width: $container-min-width; 
>     height: $container-height;   }

I think it should work once you change `conainer` to `container` :)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but it is not . the original was something in a foreign language and I changed and replaced it and added the typo. So this is not the issue

Comment: you can see @The.Bear answer - he provided in a platform.